# Como fazer uma barra de progresso com etapas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Como eu poderia fazer uma barra de progresso de etapas usando html5, css3 e js?

Um exemplo para deixar mais claro o que eu preciso fazer:

[image: Barra de Progresso em Etapas]

Tenho preferência por fazer do zero, mas, existe alguma biblioteca pronta pra isso?

Comment: Isso é basicamente uma navegação de abas. https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Realmente não sei se será útil para o seu desenvolvimento, mas existe esse site que a comunidade cria diversas barras de progresso com enfoque em bootstrap. Vou postar um exemplo sobre essa barra trabalhada em upload: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs Está aqui é trabalhada apenas com passos http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/gjm35 Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: De onde vem a informação que indica a posição atual da barra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realizei um exemplo demonstrando como criar o seu wizard/breadcrumb.

```css
/* Progress Tracker v2 */

ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li {
  width: 49%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li {
  width: 33%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li {
  width: 24%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li {
  width: 19%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li {
  width: 16%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li {
  width: 14%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li {
  width: 12%;
}
ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li {
  width: 11%;
}
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.progress .name {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.progress .step {
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}
.progress .step span {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.progress .active .name,
.progress .active .step span {
  opacity: 1;
}
.progress .step:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 0.4em;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.6em;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progress .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 0.4em;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.6em;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
  display: none;
}
.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
  display: none;
}
.progress .done .step,
.progress .done .step:before,
.progress .done .step:after,
.progress .active .step,
.progress .active .step:before {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.progress .done .step,
.progress .active .step {
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress" data-steps="4">
  <li class="done">
    <span class="name">Foo</span>
    <span class="step"><span>1</span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="done">
    <span class="name">Bar</span>
    <span class="step"><span>2</span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <span class="name">Baz</span>
    <span class="step"><span>3</span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Quux</span>
    <span class="step"><span>4</span></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

A Navegação é simplificada, basta setar as classes anteriores com `"done"` e a atual com `"active"`. você pode tornar ela dinamica com algum js realizando o progresso.

Answer (score 2):

Experimenta `progressStep.js` é um plugin **jQuery** para criar dinamicamente barras de progresso com passos numerados.

https://github.com/mateagar/progressStep

**Implementação:**

1. Criar uma `<div>` para segurar a barra de progresso; dar-lhe algumas
   dimensões (isto é, definir a largura e altura) - `progressStep.js`
   irá preencher essas dimensões com o controle.
2. Criar um objeto **jQuery** para o `<div>` e invocar o método
   `progressStep()` sobre ele para instanciar e retornar uma barra de
   progresso.
3. Chamar o método `addStep()` na barra de progresso uma vez para cada
   passo no seu processo.
4. Chamar `refreshLayout()` para setar o tamanho ea posição de tudo na
   tela.
5. Chamar `setCurrentStep()` para percorrer as etapas; opcionalmente,
   adicionar manipuladores de eventos para os passos para que você
   possa lidar com eventos de clique ou pre- / post-processamento
   conforme necessário.

**Exemplo:**

- html:

  ```
  <div id="progressBar"></div>
  ```
- Javascript:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var $progressDiv = $("#progressBar");  
      var $progressBar = $progressDiv.progressStep();  
      $progressBar.addStep("First");  
      $progressBar.addStep("Second");  
      $progressBar.addStep("Third");  
      $progressBar.refreshLayout();  
      $progressBar.setCurrentStep(0);
  });
  ```

Comment: Parece um bom plugin, coloca um exemplo.